Problem converting an image to a pdf with flutter
I need to get proof of residence, if it's not a PDF, I need to convert the image. I made some logic to do this:
_createPdf(PlatformFile file) async {
    final pdf = pw.Document();

    final image = pw.MemoryImage(
      File(file.path!).readAsBytesSync(),
    );

    pdf.addPage(pw.Page(build: (pw.Context context) {
      return pw.Center(
        child: pw.Image(image),
      ); // Center
    }),); // Page

    final String dir = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
    final String path = '$dir/pdfExemplo.pdf';
    final File newFile = File(path);
    newFile.writeAsBytesSync(await pdf.save());
    openFile2(newFile);
  }

However, the function is not creating the PDF.
I am passing the image inside the File file, creating a pdf and then trying to add the image to this created pdf
